Firebase Messaging with PWABuilder for IOS
I am using PWABuilder and Firebase Messaging for push notifications, and it is working just fine for IOS (Add to home screen), and Android.
But I can't get it to work for IOS (downloaded from the App Store) for my life.
Basically I am not even able to get the token and save it on my DB. I am not sure how can I request permission for the notification as well.
Even calling getFirebaseMessaging function outside the Notification condition does not work.
If anyone knows the solution for this... please let me know!
You can find my code below.
Thank you!
if ("Notification" in window) {
                            if (Notification?.permission === "granted") {
                              const firebaseMessagingToken =
                                getFirebaseMessaging(firebaseUser?.uid);
                            } else {
                              let permission =
                                await Notification.requestPermission();
                              if (permission === "granted") {
                                const firebaseMessagingToken =
                                  getFirebaseMessaging(firebaseUser?.uid);
                              } else {
                                console.log("nop");
                              }
                            }
                          } else {
                            console.log("no notification permitted");
                          }

getFirebaseMessaging Function
const getFirebaseMessaging = async (userUid) => {
            const { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } = await import(
              "firebase/messaging"
            );
            let messaging;
            try {
              messaging = getMessaging();
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            return getToken(messaging, {
              vapidKey:
                "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            })
              .then(async (token) => {
                if (token) {
                  const userRef = doc(getFirestore(), "xxx", xxxx);
                  updateDoc(userRef, {
                    tokens: arrayUnion(token),
                  }).then(() => {
                    return navigator?.serviceWorker.ready
                      .then((registration) => {
                        if (registration && registration?.periodicSync) {
                          return registration?.periodicSync
                            .register("firebaseMessaging", {
                              minInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000,
                            })
                            .then(() => {})
                            .catch((err) => {
                              return registration?.sync
                                .register("firebaseMessaging")
                                .then(() => {})
                                .catch((err) =>
                                  console.error(
                                    "Error registering background sync",
                                    err
                                  )
                                );
                            });
                        }
                      })
                      .catch((err) => {
                        console.error("Error registering background sync", err);
                      });
                  });
                } else {
                  console.log("no token :(");
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => console.log(err));
          };

